# How to fix this "segmentation fault 11" for this switch function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, switch-statement, text-segmentation

I'm new to c and am writing a switch function that whenever the passed in string is ), }, ], it returns false when the popped out expression isn't the matching open parentheses. (yes, it's the balanced parentheses problem...)

I can be sure that the segmentation fault only comes from this switch statement, and the code works perfectly fine without it.

my code is:

```c
switch (expr[i]) 
        { 
        case ')': if (pop(&Stack) == '{' || pop(&Stack) =='[') { 
                  return 0;}
            break; 

        case '}': if (pop(&Stack) == '(' || pop(&Stack) =='[') {
                  return 0; }
            break; 

        case ']': if (pop(&Stack) == '{' || pop(&Stack) =='(') {
                  return 0; }
            break; 
        }
```

It gives me "Segmentation fault: 11".

Comment: What is `expr`, `i`, `pop` and `Stack`?

Comment: ^ and a debugger will likely point you to the cause of the segfault.

Comment: The posted code calls 'pop()` twice for each switch case.  Strongly suggest not modifying the 'stack' at all.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the *switch* is causing the segfault.  It is more likely to be the use of `pop()`.

Is *pop* changing the stack?  If so, *pop* is twice being evaluated in:

```
 case ')':
    if (pop(&Stack) == '{'  ||  pop(&Stack) =='[')
```

when the character is `)` and the matching value popped is `(`.

To fix, restructure this area of code like this (depending on how *pop* interacts):

```
/*
 *  Have a peek at the top of stack without disrupting content
 */
char top_of_stack = pop (&Stack);
push (&Stack, top_of_stack); // put it back

switch (expr[i]) 
{ 
case ')':
     if (top_of_stack == '{' || top_of_stack == '[')
            return 0;
     break; 

case '}':
     if (top_of_stack == '(' || top_of_stack == '[')
            return 0;
     break; 

case ']':
     if (top_of_stack == '{' || top_of_stack == '(')
            return 0;
      break; 
}
```

Comment: yes yes yes thank you!!!! This solved my problem completely hope you have a nice day thank you you lightened up my day

Comment: @Barmar:  added example solution, but it assumes pop() and push() semantics (so it might not work directly).

Comment: It probably *should* pop the stack if the top is the correct balancing bracket.

Comment: @Barmar:  Yeah, *probably*.  Need to see more code to be sure.